# Win32 game loop

Tags: winapi, assembly, masm, game-loop

I'm creating simple game using Win32 API. When I click on window, a ball appear and start rolling look like bida game

My problem is when I call "InvalidateRect", my game very lag. I don't know I'm doing any thing wrong!!!

And my hPen didn't work like what I expect

Please help!!!
Thank you and sorry for my bad English

```
.386    ; use 80386 instruction
.model flat,stdcall ; uses flat memory addressing model
option casemap:none

include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc   ; windows.inc have structures and constants
include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc 
includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib ; CreateWindowEx, RegisterClassEx,...
include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib   ; ExitProcess
include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib
include C:\masm32\include\gdi32.inc 
includelib C:\masm32\lib\gdi32.lib 

.CONST
DRAWING equ 1
WAITING equ 0
PEN_COLOR equ 00000000h ; black
PEN_SIZE equ 2
BALL_SIZE equ 35
BALL_SPEED equ 20

.DATA
ClassName db 'SimpleWinClass',0
AppName db 'Ball',0

state db WAITING

vectorX dd 6
vectorY dd -7

WIN_WIDTH dd 700
WIN_HEIGHT dd 500

.DATA?
; HINSTANCE & LPSTR typedef DWORD in windows.inc
; reserve the space for future use
hInstance HINSTANCE ?

tlpoint POINT <>
brpoint POINT <>

; use for create window
wc WNDCLASSEX <?>
msg MSG <?> ; handle message
hwnd HWND ? ; handle window procedure

hdc HDC ?
ps PAINTSTRUCT <?>

time SYSTEMTIME <?>

hPen HPEN ?

.CODE
start:
    ; call GetModuleHandle(null)
    ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx
    push NULL
    call GetModuleHandle    ; module handle same as instance handle in Win32
    mov hInstance, eax  ; return an instance to handle in eax

    ; call WinMain(hInstance, hPrevInstance, CmdLine, CmdShow)
    ; our main function
    push SW_SHOW
    push NULL
    push NULL
    push hInstance
    call WinMain

    ; call ExitProcess
    push eax
    call ExitProcess

    ; Define WinMain 
    WinMain proc hInst:HINSTANCE, hPrevInst:HINSTANCE, CmdLine:LPSTR, CmdShow:DWORD
        ; Structure in msdn, define in windows.inc
        ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577(v=vs.85).aspx

        ; Load default icon
        push IDI_APPLICATION
        push NULL
        call LoadIcon
        mov wc.hIcon, eax
        mov wc.hIconSm, eax

        ; Load default cursor
        push IDC_ARROW
        push NULL
        call LoadCursor
        mov wc.hCursor, eax

        mov wc.cbSize, SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX    ; size of this structure
        mov wc.style, CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW  ; style of windows https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729176(v=vs.85).aspx
        mov wc.lpfnWndProc, OFFSET WndProc  ; andress of window procedure
        mov wc.cbClsExtra, NULL 
        mov wc.cbWndExtra, NULL
        push hInstance
        pop wc.hInstance
        mov wc.hbrBackground, COLOR_WINDOW+1    ; background color, require to add 1
        mov wc.lpszMenuName, NULL
        mov wc.lpszClassName, OFFSET ClassName

        ; we register our own class, named in ClassName
        push offset wc
        call RegisterClassEx

        ; after register ClassName, we use it to create windows compond
        ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680(v=vs.85).aspx
        push NULL
        push hInstance
        push NULL
        push NULL
        push WIN_HEIGHT
        push WIN_WIDTH
        push CW_USEDEFAULT
        push CW_USEDEFAULT
        push WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW
        push offset AppName
        push offset ClassName
        push WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
        call CreateWindowEx

        mov hwnd, eax   ; return windows handle

        ; display window
        ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx
        push CmdShow
        push hwnd
        call ShowWindow

        ; update window
        ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145167(v=vs.85).aspx
        push hwnd
        call UpdateWindow

        ; Message Loop
        MESSAGE_LOOP:
            ; get message
            ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx
            push PM_REMOVE
            push 0
            push 0
            push NULL
            push offset msg
            call PeekMessage

            ; return in eax
            ; if the function retrieves a message other than WM_QUIT, the return value is nonzero.
            ; if the function retrieves the WM_QUIT message, the return value is zero.
            cmp eax, 0
            je GAME_LOOP

            cmp msg.message, WM_QUIT
            je END_LOOP

            ; translate virtual-key messages into character messages - ASCII in WM_CHAR
            ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644955(v=vs.85).aspx
            push offset msg
            call TranslateMessage 

            ; sends the message data to the window procedure responsible for the specific window the message is for.
            ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644934(v=vs.85).aspx
            push offset msg
            call DispatchMessage

        GAME_LOOP:
            ; check that is DRAWING or not?
            cmp [state], DRAWING
            jne MESSAGE_LOOP

            push offset time
            call GetSystemTime

            cmp dword ptr[time.wMilliseconds], BALL_SPEED
            jl MESSAGE_LOOP

            push TRUE
            push NULL
            push hwnd
            call InvalidateRect

            jmp MESSAGE_LOOP

        END_LOOP:
            mov eax, msg.wParam   
        ret 
    WinMain endp

    ; Handle message with switch(notification)
    ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx
    WndProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
        cmp uMsg, WM_PAINT
        je ON_WM_PAINT

        cmp uMsg, WM_CREATE
        je ON_WM_CREATE

        cmp uMsg, WM_LBUTTONDOWN
        je ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN

        cmp uMsg, WM_DESTROY
        je ON_WM_DESTROY

        cmp uMsg, WM_QUIT
        je ON_WM_DESTROY

        cmp uMsg, WM_CLOSE
        je ON_WM_DESTROY

        jmp ON_DEFAULT

        ; user close program
        ON_WM_DESTROY:
            push NULL
            call PostQuitMessage
            jmp EXIT

        ON_WM_CREATE:
            ; create a pen with specific color and size
            ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183509(v=vs.85).aspx
            push PEN_COLOR
            push PEN_SIZE
            push PS_SOLID
            call CreatePen
            mov hPen, eax

            jmp EXIT

        ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            cmp [state], DRAWING
            je EXIT

            push lParam
            call updateXY

            ; when clicked, set state to DRAWING
            mov [state], DRAWING

            mov dword ptr[time.wMilliseconds], BALL_SPEED
            push offset time
            call SetSystemTime

            jmp EXIT

        ON_WM_PAINT:
            mov dword ptr[time.wMilliseconds], 0
            push offset time
            call SetSystemTime 

            push offset ps
            push hWnd 
            call BeginPaint
            mov hdc, eax

            ; apply pen to hdc
            push hPen
            push hdc
            call SelectObject

            call createEllipse

            push offset ps
            push hWnd
            call EndPaint

            jmp EXIT

        ON_DEFAULT:
            ; handle any message that program don't handle
            ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633572(v=vs.85).aspx
            push lParam 
            push wParam 
            push uMsg   ; message
            push hWnd   ; windows
            call DefWindowProc

            jmp EXIT

        EXIT:
            ret
    WndProc endp

    createEllipse proc
        push brpoint.y
        push brpoint.x
        push tlpoint.y
        push tlpoint.x
        push hdc
        call Ellipse

        call moveEllipse

        mov eax, WIN_WIDTH
        cmp brpoint.x, eax
        jg MEET_RIGHT_LEFT

        mov eax, WIN_HEIGHT
        cmp brpoint.y, eax
        jg MEET_BOTTOM_TOP

        cmp tlpoint.x, 0
        jl MEET_RIGHT_LEFT

        cmp tlpoint.y, 0
        jl MEET_BOTTOM_TOP

        jmp MEET_NONE

        MEET_RIGHT_LEFT:
            neg vectorX
            jmp MEET_NONE

        MEET_BOTTOM_TOP:
            neg vectorY
            jmp MEET_NONE

        MEET_NONE:

        ret
    createEllipse endp

    moveEllipse proc
        mov eax, dword ptr[vectorX]
        mov ecx, dword ptr[vectorY]

        add tlpoint.x, eax
        add tlpoint.y, ecx
        add brpoint.x, eax
        add brpoint.y, ecx

        ret
    moveEllipse endp

    updateXY proc lParam:LPARAM
        mov eax, lParam

        ; get low word that contain x
        xor ebx, ebx
        mov bx, ax

        mov tlpoint.x, ebx
        mov brpoint.x, ebx
        add brpoint.x, BALL_SIZE

        ; get high word that contain y
        mov eax, lParam
        shr eax, 16

        mov tlpoint.y, eax
        mov brpoint.y, eax
        add brpoint.y, BALL_SIZE

        ret
    updateXY endp

end start
```

Comment: Try some debugging. You don't check return values. Perhaps some of these calls fail. Where does the program spend its time? And using asm is making your life very hard for absolutely no benefit at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to use the system time for speed issues. Use your procedure `moveEllipse` instead and increase `vectorX` and `vectorY` for more speed. `InvalidateRec` should be called if there is a real update needed. You can reach that by using a timer instead of changing and checking the system time: [`SetTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx).

```
.386    ; use 80386 instruction
.model flat,stdcall ; uses flat memory addressing model
option casemap:none

include C:\masm32\include\windows.inc   ; windows.inc have structures and constants
include C:\masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib C:\masm32\lib\user32.lib ; CreateWindowEx, RegisterClassEx,...
include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib   ; ExitProcess
include C:\masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib C:\masm32\lib\masm32.lib
include C:\masm32\include\gdi32.inc
includelib C:\masm32\lib\gdi32.lib

.CONST
DRAWING equ 1
WAITING equ 0
PEN_COLOR equ 00000000h ; black
PEN_SIZE equ 2
BALL_SIZE equ 35
BALL_SPEED equ 20

.DATA
ClassName db 'SimpleWinClass',0
AppName db 'Ball',0

state db WAITING

vectorX dd 19
vectorY dd -19

WIN_WIDTH dd 700
WIN_HEIGHT dd 500

.DATA?
; HINSTANCE & LPSTR typedef DWORD in windows.inc
; reserve the space for future use
hInstance HINSTANCE ?

tlpoint POINT <>
brpoint POINT <>

; use for create window
wc WNDCLASSEX <?>
msg MSG <?> ; handle message
hwnd HWND ? ; handle window procedure

hdc HDC ?
ps PAINTSTRUCT <?>

time SYSTEMTIME <?>

hPen HPEN ?

.CODE
start:
    ; call GetModuleHandle(null)
    ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199(v=vs.85).aspx
    push NULL
    call GetModuleHandle    ; module handle same as instance handle in Win32
    mov hInstance, eax  ; return an instance to handle in eax

    ; call WinMain(hInstance, hPrevInstance, CmdLine, CmdShow)
    ; our main function
    push SW_SHOW
    push NULL
    push NULL
    push hInstance
    call WinMain

    ; call ExitProcess
    push eax
    call ExitProcess

    ; Define WinMain
    WinMain proc hInst:HINSTANCE, hPrevInst:HINSTANCE, CmdLine:LPSTR, CmdShow:DWORD
        ; Structure in msdn, define in windows.inc
        ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577(v=vs.85).aspx

        ; Load default icon
        push IDI_APPLICATION
        push NULL
        call LoadIcon
        mov wc.hIcon, eax
        mov wc.hIconSm, eax

        ; Load default cursor
        push IDC_ARROW
        push NULL
        call LoadCursor
        mov wc.hCursor, eax

        mov wc.cbSize, SIZEOF WNDCLASSEX    ; size of this structure
        mov wc.style, CS_HREDRAW or CS_VREDRAW  ; style of windows https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff729176(v=vs.85).aspx
        mov wc.lpfnWndProc, OFFSET WndProc  ; andress of window procedure
        mov wc.cbClsExtra, NULL
        mov wc.cbWndExtra, NULL
        push hInstance
        pop wc.hInstance
        mov wc.hbrBackground, COLOR_WINDOW+1    ; background color, require to add 1
        mov wc.lpszMenuName, NULL
        mov wc.lpszClassName, OFFSET ClassName

        ; we register our own class, named in ClassName
        push offset wc
        call RegisterClassEx

        ; after register ClassName, we use it to create windows compond
        ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680(v=vs.85).aspx
        push NULL
        push hInstance
        push NULL
        push NULL
        push WIN_HEIGHT
        push WIN_WIDTH
        push CW_USEDEFAULT
        push CW_USEDEFAULT
        push WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW
        push offset AppName
        push offset ClassName
        push WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
        call CreateWindowEx

        mov hwnd, eax   ; return windows handle

        ; display window
        ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx
        push CmdShow
        push hwnd
        call ShowWindow

        ; update window
        ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145167(v=vs.85).aspx
        push hwnd
        call UpdateWindow

        ; Message Loop
        MESSAGE_LOOP:
            ; get message
            ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx
            push 0
            push 0
            push NULL
            push offset msg
            call GetMessage

            ; return in eax
            ; if the function retrieves a message other than WM_QUIT, the return value is nonzero.
            ; if the function retrieves the WM_QUIT message, the return value is zero.
            test eax, eax
            jle END_LOOP

            ; translate virtual-key messages into character messages - ASCII in WM_CHAR
            ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644955(v=vs.85).aspx
            push offset msg
            call TranslateMessage

            ; sends the message data to the window procedure responsible for the specific window the message is for.
            ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644934(v=vs.85).aspx
            push offset msg
            call DispatchMessage

            jmp MESSAGE_LOOP

        END_LOOP:
            mov eax, msg.wParam
        ret
    WinMain endp

    TimerProc PROC thwnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, idEvent:UINT, dwTime:DWORD
            push TRUE
            push NULL
            push thwnd
            call InvalidateRect
            ret
    TimerProc ENDP

    ; Handle message with switch(notification)
    ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx
    WndProc proc hWnd:HWND, uMsg:UINT, wParam:WPARAM, lParam:LPARAM
        cmp uMsg, WM_PAINT
        je ON_WM_PAINT

        cmp uMsg, WM_CREATE
        je ON_WM_CREATE

        cmp uMsg, WM_LBUTTONDOWN
        je ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN

        cmp uMsg, WM_DESTROY
        je ON_WM_DESTROY

        cmp uMsg, WM_QUIT
        je ON_WM_DESTROY

        cmp uMsg, WM_CLOSE
        je ON_WM_DESTROY

        jmp ON_DEFAULT

        ; user close program
        ON_WM_DESTROY:
            push NULL
            call PostQuitMessage
            jmp EXIT

        ON_WM_CREATE:
            ; create a pen with specific color and size
            ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183509(v=vs.85).aspx
            push PEN_COLOR
            push PEN_SIZE
            push PS_SOLID
            call CreatePen
            mov hPen, eax

            jmp EXIT

        ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            cmp [state], DRAWING
            je EXIT

            push lParam
            call updateXY

            ; when clicked, set state to DRAWING
            mov [state], DRAWING

            push OFFSET TimerProc
            push 20
            push 1
            push hwnd
            call SetTimer

;            mov dword ptr[time.wMilliseconds], BALL_SPEED
;            push offset time
;            call SetSystemTime

            jmp EXIT

        ON_WM_PAINT:
            mov dword ptr[time.wMilliseconds], 0

            push offset ps
            push hWnd
            call BeginPaint
            mov hdc, eax

            ; apply pen to hdc
            push hPen
            push hdc
            call SelectObject

            call createEllipse

            push offset ps
            push hWnd
            call EndPaint

            jmp EXIT

        ON_DEFAULT:
            ; handle any message that program don't handle
            ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633572(v=vs.85).aspx
            push lParam
            push wParam
            push uMsg   ; message
            push hWnd   ; windows
            call DefWindowProc

            jmp EXIT

        EXIT:
            ret
    WndProc endp

    createEllipse proc
        push brpoint.y
        push brpoint.x
        push tlpoint.y
        push tlpoint.x
        push hdc
        call Ellipse

        call moveEllipse

        mov eax, WIN_WIDTH
        cmp brpoint.x, eax
        jg MEET_RIGHT_LEFT

        mov eax, WIN_HEIGHT
        cmp brpoint.y, eax
        jg MEET_BOTTOM_TOP

        cmp tlpoint.x, 0
        jl MEET_RIGHT_LEFT

        cmp tlpoint.y, 0
        jl MEET_BOTTOM_TOP

        jmp MEET_NONE

        MEET_RIGHT_LEFT:
            neg vectorX
            jmp MEET_NONE

        MEET_BOTTOM_TOP:
            neg vectorY
            jmp MEET_NONE

        MEET_NONE:

        ret
    createEllipse endp

    moveEllipse proc
        mov eax, dword ptr[vectorX]
        mov ecx, dword ptr[vectorY]

        add tlpoint.x, eax
        add tlpoint.y, ecx
        add brpoint.x, eax
        add brpoint.y, ecx

        ret
    moveEllipse endp

    updateXY proc lParam:LPARAM
        mov eax, lParam

        ; get low word that contain x
        xor ebx, ebx
        mov bx, ax

        mov tlpoint.x, ebx
        mov brpoint.x, ebx
        add brpoint.x, BALL_SIZE

        ; get high word that contain y
        mov eax, lParam
        shr eax, 16

        mov tlpoint.y, eax
        mov brpoint.y, eax
        add brpoint.y, BALL_SIZE

        ret
    updateXY endp

end start
```

Comment: That's a stack overflow waiting to happen. You probably meant to `call PeekMessage` in place of `GetMessage`. The timer ID is also inappropriately chosen. It is of type `UINT_PTR` so that you can pass a unique memory address.

Comment: @IInspectable: I meant `GetMessage` and removed the wrong push. Sorry. `UINT_PTR` means [*"An unsigned integer, whose length is dependent on processor word size"*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc248915.aspx). It doesn't need to be unique and have to be a direct value, not a memory address.

Comment: It needs to be unique for a timer. And the memory address of a distinct entity is the easiest way to guarantee uniqueness. That is why the ID is a `UINT_PTR` (vs. a `UINT`, which would be **way** sufficient to hold a unique ID for the maximum supported concurrent timers). See [How do I call SetTimer with a timer ID that is guaranteed not to conflict with any other timer ID?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150924-00/?p=91521).

Answer (score 0):

You are handling a single message in between running your `GAME_LOOP`. This does not bode well. Instead, drain the entire message queue in between screen updates. The solution is simple: Add

```
jmp MESSAGE_LOOP
```

right after

```
call DispatchMessage
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still lag :(

Comment: @ĐinhVănKiệt: Well, a call to `SetSystemTime` to implement local, process-private synchronization isn't ideal either. There's probably lots more wrong with the code, but my answer addresses the most glaring issue with respect to latency.